# Git, when switching branches I get error: "Deletion of directory '<dirname>' failed. Should I try again?" Started after I set custom folder icon

Tags: windows, git, msysgit, git-bash

I'm using the git bash on windows (v1.7.10 msysgit).  I set some custom folder icons on some subfolders in my repo the other day and ever since then I can no longer switch between branches without an error like:

```
blake@ComputerName /c/csharp (AD_NativeRefactor)
$ git checkout master
Deletion of directory 'AllertFullfillmentDB' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
```

The directory that fails isn't always the same but it's always 1 of the 3 subfolders that I set a custom icon on.

- I have since removed the custom icon's with restore defaults.
- I've checked file permissions (it's no different then other folders in repo).
- I've tried using Unlocker and no nothing is locking the directory.
- I've tried restarting windows.

Not really sure what to do next.  Any ideas?

Comment: Would the issue persists if you clone again your repo in a different location?

Comment: I've had this issue as well and I believe unlocker indicated that sh.exe was holding the directory. I don't have a firm solution yet. I will note that it *generally* does not actually cause any harm (but always check `git status` to be sure)

Comment: @VonC - fresh clone doesn't have the issue.  So, that's probably the simplest solution.

Comment: @VonC if you want to post an answer, I'll mark it as accepted and delete mine.

Comment: @Christopher: What you linked is not the right function (you can tell by the fact that it prints a different error message). The OP is getting the message from [this function](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/mingw.c#L253).

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Ah nice catch. I'll delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comment, cloning the repo in a different location is the simplest way to "reset", and see if the issue persists.

Apparently, setting up custom icon on some folders on the repo has the side effect of preventing checkout between branches, because Windows would keep handle opened on some of the directories that need to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I think my solution worked without moving the repo to a new directory:

1. I've restored the folder to its defaults, and unchecked the 'read only'.
2. I've answered 'no' to the git program question about retry.
3. Finally, I've made a git status, and there was only a desktop.ini file that was marked as modified, and I've simply removed it.

That's all, I have my master again as clean and operating.

Answer (score -4):

Try using `chmod -R 777 *` in the root of your project directory, then retry switching branch

Comment: With 777 you are giving access and execution rights to everything. Very bad security issues might ensue. This is not recommended at all.